# Removing dynamically created divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: Just so I asks questions better next time. I got a -1 what did I do wrong?

I'm adding quite a lot of html dynamically and want to be able to remove them also one by one.

Below the JQuery. I want to be able to remove the whole $("#row1' + (counter) + '") div including all divs in it by clicking the remove button under it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FullContCoder/Sf9r5/1/

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 0;

    $(".addButton").click(function() {

    var test =    $( '<div id="row1' + (counter) + '" class="row"><div class="col-md-2"><p><small>Placement Name:</small></p><input id="inputPlacement' + (counter) + '" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="placementName" placeholder="ex: Homepage">' +
            '</div><div class="col-md-3"><p><small>URL:</small></p><input id="inputURL" type="url" class="form-control input-sm" name="url" placeholder="ex: http://www.allure.com"></div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><p><small>Select a Date and Time:</small></p></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">' +
            '<div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"><input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly=""><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i>' +
            '</span></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker"><input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small"><span class="add-on">' +
            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span></div></div></div><div class="col-md-2"><p><small>Recurring:</small></p><select id="recurring" class="form-control input-sm">' +
            '<option name="daily" value="daily">Daily</option><option name="weekly" value="weekly">Weekly</option><option name="month" value="month">Month</option></select></div>' +
            '<div class="col-md-2"><p><small>Day of Week:</small></p><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="mon" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Mon</label>' +
            '</div><div class="col-md-6"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="fri" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Fri</label></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">' +
            '<label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="tue" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Tue</label></div><div class="col-md-6"><label class="checkbox-inline">' +
            '<input id="sat" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Sat</label></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="checkbox-inline">' +
            '<input id="wen" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Wed</label></div><div class="col-md-6"><label class="checkbox-inline">' +
            '<input id="sun" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Sun</label></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="checkbox-inline">' +
            '<input id="thu" name="test" type="checkbox" value="1"> Thu</label></div></div></div><div class="col-md-1"><p><small>Remove:</small></p>' +
            '<button type="button" class="removeButton btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></button></div></div>' )



        $('.removeButton').click(function() {
            $("#row1' + (counter) + '").remove();
        });

        counter++;


       $("#row1").after(test);
    });




});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to add events to dynamically created elements. And use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the first element that matches the selector. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.removeButton',function() {
     $(this).closest("div.row").remove();
});
```

You need to move your remove button `click` handler outside of add button `click` handler.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/Sf9r5/3/)**

Comment: In my case I needed to remove both a preceding select menu as well as the remove button itself: `$(document).on('click','.removesection',function() {
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).remove();
 });`

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here to bind `click` event to your button since it has been added dynamically to the DOM.

2) Use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to remove the closest matching ancestor `.row` and remove redundant `counter` variable here:

3) You also need to move your `click` handler of remove button outside of the `click` handler of the add button.

Final code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addButton").click(function () {
        var test = .....
        $("#row1").after(test);
    });

    $('.removeButton').click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".row").remove();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sf9r5/4/)**

Comment: Updated fiddle with your code, doesn't do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/FullContCoder/Sf9r5/2/

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could award more then one person correct answer so I chose the fastest. Can't believe how fast the answers come in.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeButton', function(){
    $('#row1' + counter).remove();
});
```